# How to make custom non-linear convolution-like layer to be fast in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I need to make convolution-like layer in tensorflow2 (and then export graph to neural accelerator).
Filter takes 7x7 area and produces one pixel, but it is non-linear and uses abs function, so it's impossible to directly utilize optimized nn.conv2d function.

I've tried to make the custom layer, code works, but its an abysmally slow code (10-20 sec for one image row!) for the filter that should run only a bit slower than convolution one. When I tried to make the convolutional layer the same way, it also was too slow. What is the best way to implement filter as in the code below?

This is the minimal example of filter that is non-linear and slow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class FilterLayer (tf.keras.layers.Layer) :
def __init__(self) :
    super(FilterLayer, self).__init__()
    self.offset = 4
    
def build(self, input_shape) :
    pass


def call(self, input): 
    output = tf.Variable(np.zeros((input.shape[0] - self.offset * 2, input.shape[1] - self.offset * 2)), dtype=tf.uint8)
    
    a = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float32)
    s = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.float32)
    d = tf.Variable(3, dtype=tf.float32)
    f = tf.Variable(4, dtype=tf.float32)
    g = tf.Variable(5, dtype=tf.float32)
    for y in range(self.offset, input.shape[0] - self.offset) :
        for x in range(self.offset, input.shape[1] - self.offset) :

            q = tf.cast(input[y][x], dtype=tf.float32)
            w = tf.cast(input[y+1][x+1], dtype=tf.float32)
            e = tf.cast(input[y-1][x+1], dtype=tf.float32)
            r = tf.cast(input[y+1][x-1], dtype=tf.float32)
            t = tf.cast(input[y-1][x-1], dtype=tf.float32)
            summ = a*q+tf.abs(s*w-d*e)*tf.abs(f*r-g*t)
            tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(output, [(y-4, x-4)], [summ])
        print(y)
    return output
q = FilterLayer()
q(tf.Variable(np.ones((3000, 3000)), dtype=tf.uint8))
```

For comparison, ordinary convolution executes almost instantly (example is taken from documentation, it differs from this filter)

```
x_in = np.ones((3000, 3000), dtype=np.uint8)
print(x_in.shape)
x_in = x_in[np.newaxis][..., np.newaxis]
print(x_in.shape)

kernel_in = np.array([
 [ [[2, 0.1]], [[3, 0.2]] ],
 [ [[0, 0.3]],[[1, 0.4]] ], ])

x = tf.constant(x_in, dtype=tf.float32)
kernel = tf.constant(kernel_in, dtype=tf.float32)
out_res = tf.nn.conv2d(x, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
print(out_res.shape)
```

P.S. I don't need to use back-propagation nor training for this filter, all coefficients are known